# Linux system + bootable windows on a USB: How to run?

Tags: boot, live-usb, windows-10, vpn, cluster

I installed a bootable windows 10 on a usb key. Now, the question is how to use the windows without leaving the linux. My purpose to use a windows is to have access to a cluster with a VPN. The license for VPN is not bought for my version of linux. So I decided to install windows and go through that. However, as my purpose is to retrieve data from the cluster and post process them on my linux system, I would like to know, how I can run the windows while linux and its folders are open. Like to have a terminal from windows being open and copy the data to the folders of linux.

Comment: I wanted to see if in general there is a mean to do what I described. My system is Kubuntu 14.04 which is an obsolete version. But I can not upgrade it as there are many software installed on it.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: I knew that if I mention kubuntu, I will get such a comment closing my question without helping me. While in majority of cases, answers given for ubuntu work pretty well for kubuntu.

Comment: The issue is not Kubuntu.  All 14.04 releases are off-topic (either EOL or ESM).  Kubuntu is as on-topic as main Ubuntu is, meaning 16.04 is the oldest supported for main Ubuntu, 18.04 the oldest Kubuntu, but I'd only have provided a FYI you're EOL for Kubuntu 16.04 & ignored it.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: I checked my version again and is 16.04. Sorry for the mistake above. Now, do you have any answer to my main question ?

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks, or use Ubuntu's default Unity desktop (*which still is supported*).

Comment: Looks like you need Windows installed in a Virtual Machine, with Ubuntu as host OS.

Comment: Yes. Does it mean that the installation of windows on the usb key is useless ? Or could I use it be used as a Virtual Machine ?

Comment: I suspect you would need to install Windows on Virtual hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please provide me some links to have some idea where I should start from ? This virtual hardware can be a usb key ?

Comment: You can put your Windows virtual machine, (VDI file), on a USB stick and run it from VirtualBox installed on an internal drive, It gets to be a little slower than if put on the internal drive. You can Install Virtual box in Ubuntu that is installed on a USB stick also, but that is very slow. I believe you can run a Windows to Go USB stick in QEMU running in Ubuntu, but I have not tried it. Rufus will make a Windows to Go stick but you still need a license or ...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/QemuEmulator

Comment: Thanks all. As you suggested I am installing a virtual machine on my system. However, I have a problem in terms of virtualization: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271026/enable-vitualization-on-ubuntu . Do you know how I can solve this issue ?