# How do I enable virtualization for Ubuntu on Thinkpad?

Tags: virtualization, thinkpad

I am installing a virtual machine on my Ubuntu system to use Windows 10. There is a message about enabling the virtualization. However, the settings are not similar to what is shown on other platforms. How I can enable the virtualization with the below settings?

[image: ndo]

Comment: https://support.lenovo.com/pt/en/solutions/ht500006

Comment: Thanks Cameron. I've already found the website you are mentioning. But the problem is the settings shown there are not similar with mine. I have Virtualization in the security tab and there is no bottom beside it to indicate enable/disable. So by pressing this option, this is the menu I have. Here, I don't know which option need to be changed in order to activate the virtualization.

Comment: Is there any command line with which the virtualization can be enabled ?

Comment: Virtualization extensions must be enabled in the BIOS; Ubuntu can't help you there.  Can you add a picture of the virtualization options you are seeing in your BIOS?

Comment: When I click on the virtualization, I have this menu. It seems that has nothing to do with virtualization options but I have only that.